# Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar. running egg_info

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to install an app requirements on my local machine.  However, I am stuck on the following error that seems to be related to cython.  This occurs when I run the following code on Windows 10:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

which results in the following error.  Can someone please let me know what is the cause of this error?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Eli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-95mpxv94\\cython_6c43cf9f18634be392cac50ea5fe94e4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Eli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-95mpxv94\\cython_6c43cf9f18634be392cac50ea5fe94e4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-oo__ie66'
       cwd: C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-95mpxv94\cython_6c43cf9f18634be392cac50ea5fe94e4\
  Complete output (43 lines):
  Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
  running egg_info
  creating C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-oo__ie66\Cython.egg-info
  writing C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-oo__ie66\Cython.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-oo__ie66\Cython.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-oo__ie66\Cython.egg-info\entry_points.txt
  writing top-level names to C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-oo__ie66\Cython.egg-info\top_level.txt
  writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-oo__ie66\Cython.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-95mpxv94\cython_6c43cf9f18634be392cac50ea5fe94e4\setup.py", line 228, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 299, in run
      self.find_sources()
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 306, in find_sources
      mm.run()
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 541, in run
      self.add_defaults()
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 578, in add_defaults
      sdist.add_defaults(self)
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 228, in add_defaults
      self._add_defaults_ext()
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 311, in _add_defaults_ext
      build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
      cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
      self.finalize_options()
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-95mpxv94\cython_6c43cf9f18634be392cac50ea5fe94e4\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 20, in finalize_options
      self.distribution.ext_modules[:] = cythonize(
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-95mpxv94\cython_6c43cf9f18634be392cac50ea5fe94e4\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 959, in cythonize
      module_list, module_metadata = create_extension_list(
    File "C:\Users\Eli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-95mpxv94\cython_6c43cf9f18634be392cac50ea5fe94e4\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 752, in create_extension_list
      elif isinstance(patterns, basestring) or not isinstance(patterns, collections.Iterable):
  AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/9b/706dac7338c2860cd063a28cdbf5e9670995eaea408abbf2e88ba070d90d/Cython-0.29.14.tar.gz#sha256=e4d6bb8703d0319eb04b7319b12ea41580df44fd84d83ccda13ea463c6801414 (from https://pypi.org/simple/cython/) (requires-python:>=2.6, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*). Command errored out with exit status 1: python se
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you just need to update Cython. The version you have meets the requirements but predates Python 3.10

Comment: but this version seems to be the latest official version by cython.org.  Have not been able any later version than this:

Comment: prior messages before error:

Comment: Collecting cython==0.29.14
  Using cached Cython-0.29.14.tar.gz (2.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Eli22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0]

Comment: The last offical version is 0.29.24 I think

Comment: Thanks.  The issue was that cython==0.29.14 version is NOT YET COMPATIBLE WITH PYTHON 10.  I ran the requirements.txt with Python version 8.8 and the issue was resolved.  Thanks for your help.  This issue is now closed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `cython==0.29.14` version is not yet compatible with Python 10. I ran the `requirements.txt` with Python version 8.8 and the issue was resolved.